# Parse HTML Offline

Tags: java, html, eclipse, parsing

Are there any HTML parsers that parse HTML docs offline, i.e. stored on your computer? If so, can anyone name some good ones please?

UPDATE: Hah, NVM, found the answer, would anyone be able to provide an example of this in html Jericho?

UPDATE2: I thought I had found the answer but I am wrong, mistook InputStream for FileInputStream :(

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Your current browser can parse HTML offline ;)

Comment: I bet there is an HTML parser in each current language, which one can you write handle?

Comment: A language tag would be quite helpful.

Comment: There are example for Jericho here: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html - about halfway down the page where it says "Sample Programs".

Comment: @Tatu: I'm talking about removing tags, searching for specific tags, deleting whitespace etc
@Georg: Done
@Mark Byers: I've seen those and not one of them shows how to parse a file thats stored on my comp, it's all for html pages actively on the net.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a few you could look at:

- For Python: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)
- For .NET: [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)
- For Java: [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)

Answer (score 0):

How about [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

[Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/about.html) has an HTML parser as a subcomponent. Javadoc [here](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/apidocs/org/apache/nutch/parse/html/package-summary.html).